# Syntax to add second email address to cc field

Tags: email, ms-access, vba

When I click the send e-mail button in MS Access, the following runs:

```
EmailDatabaseObject  
To: =DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" & Nz([Assigned To],0))  
CC: =IIf(DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" & 
     Nz([Opened By],0))=DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" &
     Nz([Assigned To],0)),"",DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" & Nz([Opened By],0)))
```

and other items for subject, message and so on.

I would like to add another e-mail address to the CC field.

Comment: Add this at the end of your CC code: `;email@email.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `CC` field in your macro currently contains an `iif` statement, the required modification depends on whether you wish to send the email to your additional email address for **all cases**, or only for the case in which **the `iif` test expression is validated**.

Currently, your `iif` statement is performing the following test:

```vb
=IIf
(
    DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" & Nz([Opened By],0))=
    DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" & Nz([Assigned To],0)),
    "",
    DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" & Nz([Opened By],0))
)
```

That is to say:

*If the contact email address for the `Opened By` ID is equal to the contact email address for the `Assigned To` ID, then the `CC` field is blank (since the `To` field already contains the `Assigned To` email address); else use the `Opened By` email address.*

The easiest modification would of course be to simply concatenate the additional email address to the start or end of the `iif` statement, e.g.:

```vb
=IIf
(
    DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" & Nz([Opened By],0))=
    DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" & Nz([Assigned To],0)),
    "",
    DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" & Nz([Opened By],0))
) 
& ";email@email.com"
```

```vb
="email@email.com;" &
IIf
(
    DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" & Nz([Opened By],0))=
    DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" & Nz([Assigned To],0)),
    "",
    DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" & Nz([Opened By],0))
)
```

However, this would yield a leading/trailing semi-colon for the case in which the `Opened By` email address is equal to the `Assigned To` email address.

Therefore, to ensure that you are not left with a leading/trailing semi-colon, you may wish to use:

```vb
=IIf
(
    DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" & Nz([Opened By],0))=
    DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" & Nz([Assigned To],0)),
    "email@email.com",
    DLookUp("[E-mail Address]","Contacts","[ID]=" & Nz([Opened By],0)) & ";email@email.com"
)
```

Comment: Nicely explained!

Answer (score 1):

**CC should be**

`CC: =IIf(DLookup("[E-mail Address]", "Contacts", "[ID]=" & Nz([Opened By], 0)) = DLookup("[E-mail Address]", "Contacts", "[ID]=" & Nz([Assigned To], 0)), "", DLookup("[E-mail Address]", "Contacts", "[ID]=" & Nz([Opened By], 0)) & ";" & "email@email.com")`

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate existing IIF(.....) with the desired email address. 
Pseudocode :

```
a = IIF(......)
b = "email@email.com"
c = a + ";" + b
.
.
.
CC = c
```